# getting hidden input element ID using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden input field on the page and I wanted to  get the ID of it using jQuery.I am using the below statement but it is coming out as null.Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var hiddenID = $('input[id~="HiddenCounter"]').attr('id');
});
```

In the source view of the page I can see my element

```
<input type="hidden" name="longstringgeneratedbyASP.Net_HiddenCounter" id="longstringgeneratedbyASP.Net_HiddenCounter"/>
```

Comment: Your `<input>` tag in the question has an extra double-quote after `id=`. Is that in the real code?

Comment: nope..just edited the code.

Comment: You know I would +1 somebody's answer if it told what, exactly, the selector stuff (`*=, ~=, $=`). I know what they mean. You know what they mean but what they mean is the essence of the answer to the OP's question. His ~= can't work because it's looking for a word.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code :

```
var hiddenID = $('input[name$="HiddenCounter"]').attr('id');
```

Comment: @user505210  Please accept the asnwer if my post solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:hidden` selector. eg

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hiddenID = $('input:hidden').attr('id');
});
```

## EDITED

your id attribute is null

```
<input ... id="" longstringgeneratedbyASP.Net_HiddenCounter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error, there is an extra `"` at the beginning of the `id` attribute `id=""long...`

```
<input type="hidden" name="longstringgeneratedbyASP.Net_HiddenCounter" id="longstringgeneratedbyASP.Net_HiddenCounter"/>
```

also change the selector to

```
var hiddenID = $('input:hidden[id$="HiddenCounter"]').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .NET-generated ID with the control's ClientID property.  Your javascript would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var hiddenID = '<%=HiddenCounter.ClientID%>';
});
```